# Как превратить текст из textarea в массив объектов на js?

Tags: javascript

Не могу разобраться с этим моментом.Помогите,пожалуйста. У меня есть текст:

```
Большая Очаковская, вааса 3
Измайловский проспект дом 47, кв 15, Эспоо 2
Красногорск, деревня Глухово, Симпл 1
Краснопролетарская, 9 - 41, Вааса 4 Симпл 1
Новослободская 23, Вааса 2 2шт, вааса3.
проезд Шокальского 49 к1, кв. 281, Эспоо 3. Симпл 1
Рокоссовского, Вааса 2
Складочная,4,кв162(2 подъезд), Эспоо 32
ул. Римского-Корсакова, 11к4, кв 13, Симпл 1 краска, 6шт.
ул.Сергея Эйзенштейна, 6, Симпл 2
Феодосийская 7к6, Симпл 1 частично 8шт,
Ярославское шоссе д8.1, Эспоо 4 краска
```

В нем написаны адрес и через запятую товар.Хочу превратить в такого вида:

```
const arr=[
        {"address":"Ярославское шоссе, 8к1","product":"васса3"},
        
    ];
```

Что я сделал:

```js
const formElement = document.getElementById('form');
const buttonElement = document.getElementById('button');
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.getElementById('textarea').value);
  const arStr = [];
  arStr.push(document.getElementById('textarea').value);
  const result = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split('\n');
  console.log(result);
  let size = 1;
  let subarray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil(result.length / size); i++) {
    subarray[i] = result.slice((i * size), (i * size) + size);
  }
  console.log(subarray);
  subarray.forEach((element) => {
    const count = (element[0].match(/\,/g) || []).length;
    console.log(count);

  });
});
```

```html
<form class="form" id="form">
<textarea id="textarea" name="textarea"  rows="10" cols="70" >
</textarea>
<button type="submit" id="button">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Я разделил текст на подмассивы, а дальше хотел разделить один элемент массива на два. То есть отделить адрес от товара.Хотел сделать под условие, подсчитав запятые, но понял, что запутался.Буду рад любой помощи)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По запятым у вас получается двойственность, на самом деле вы должны знать что и где начинается. Я лишь предположил существования списка продуктов, разделил по запятым и предположил что после того как начинается продукты адресов нет. Пользуйтесь.

мелкие недочеты по типу трима по краям думаю вы простите.

```js
const inputStrs = ["Большая Очаковская, вааса 3",
"Измайловский проспект дом 47, кв 15, Эспоо 2",
"Красногорск, деревня Глухово, Симпл 1",
"Краснопролетарская, 9 - 41, Вааса 4 Симпл 1",
"Новослободская 23, Вааса 2 2шт, вааса3.",
"проезд Шокальского 49 к1, кв. 281, Эспоо 3. Симпл 1",
"Рокоссовского, Вааса 2",
"Складочная,4,кв162(2 подъезд), Эспоо 32",
"ул. Римского-Корсакова, 11к4, кв 13, Симпл 1 краска, 6шт.",
"ул.Сергея Эйзенштейна, 6, Симпл 2",
"Феодосийская 7к6, Симпл 1 частично 8шт,",
"Ярославское шоссе д8.1, Эспоо 4 краска"];

const products = ["эспоо","симпл","вааса"];

var result = inputStrs.map(str => str.split(",").reduce(
(acc, item) => {
  if (products.filter(product=> item.toLowerCase().includes(product)).length > 0 ||      acc.product != "") {
    acc.product +=( acc.product!=""?",":"") + item;
  } else {
    acc.address +=( acc.address!=""?",":"") + item;
  }
  return acc;
}

, { address: "", product:""})
);

console.log(result)
```